# how to use SET and COPY in CMD?

Tags: c#, copy, cmd, set

working on this in C# Win Forms.

how do set a variable and after run the command copy ?
as the code is now, the Process1.startInfo.Arguments = "/k **SET** etc. etc." is overwritting by the "/k **COPY** etc. etc." command and there for not executed.

```
    public void OutputBtn_Process_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo fi in listBox1.Items)
        {
            Process process1 = new Process();
            process1.StartInfo.Arguments ="/k Set filename ="+fi.Name;
            process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k copy /b %filename% test.txt";
            //process1.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            process1.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fi.FullName);
            process1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: perhaps you need to separate the StartInfo.Arguments first run the Set CMD then Run the Copy CMD

Comment: Why would you use environment variables?!! LOL

Comment: its for printing out commands to a LPT1 port ^^ works way better than printdocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "copy /b \"" + fi.Name + "\" test.txt";`

Answer (score 3):

RE:  Environment Variables

There's a collection of them off of ProcessStartInfo ([ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables)) that you can use.

RE:  Copying a file.
Use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
File.Copy(src, destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide information on what you are trying to achieve the right way to do whatever your code is doing is File.Copy.